# Can't send messages both ways with a TCP connection

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make code so that a non-portforwarded computer can connect via TCP to a portforwarded one and messages will be able to be sent both ways. Could you please look through the following code and see why I can't get messages to send? I've put a lot of effort into getting this to work and it hasn't :C
Form1 should try to connect to Form2, and Form2 should accept the connection and send a message.

Form1 (non-portforwarded computer):

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
    Imports System.Threading
    Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary
    Public Class Form1
    Dim SenderClient As TcpClient
    Dim ReceiverClient As TcpClient
    Dim Receiver As TcpListener
    Dim Listening As New Thread(AddressOf Listen)
    Dim GetMessage As New Thread(AddressOf ReceiveMessage)
    Dim BF As New BinaryFormatter
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CreateNewReceiver(44444)
        Listening.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CreateNewSender()
        Connect("loopback", 55555)
    End Sub
    Private Sub CreateNewSender()
        Try
            SenderClient.Client.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        SenderClient = New TcpClient
    End Sub
    Private Sub CreateNewReceiver(ReceiverPort As Integer)
        Try
            Receiver.Server.Close()
            ReceiverClient.Client.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Receiver = New TcpListener(ReceiverPort)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Connect(IPAddress As String, SenderPort As Integer)
1:      Try
            SenderClient.Connect(IPAddress, SenderPort)
        Catch ex As Exception
            If MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to Form2: " & vbNewLine & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry Then
                GoTo 1
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub ReceiveMessage()
        While ReceiverClient.Connected = True
            MsgBox(BF.Deserialize(ReceiverClient.GetStream))
        End While
    End Sub
    Private Sub Listen()
        Try
            While ReceiverClient.Connected = False
                Receiver.Start()
                ReceiverClient = Receiver.AcceptTcpClient
            End While
            GetMessage.Start()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form2 (portforwarded computer):

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form2
    Dim SenderClient As TcpClient
    Dim ReceiverClient As TcpClient
    Dim Receiver As TcpListener
    Dim Listening As New Thread(AddressOf Listen)
    Dim GetMessage As New Thread(AddressOf ReceiveMessage)
    Dim BF As New BinaryFormatter
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CreateNewSender()
        CreateNewReceiver(55555)
        Listening.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub CreateNewSender()
        Try
            SenderClient.Client.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        SenderClient = New TcpClient
    End Sub
    Private Sub CreateNewReceiver(ReceiverPort As Integer)
        Try
            Receiver.Server.Close()
            ReceiverClient.Client.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Receiver = New TcpListener(ReceiverPort)
    End Sub
    Private Sub ReceiveMessage()
        While ReceiverClient.Connected = True
            BF.Serialize(SenderClient.GetStream, "I've accepted the connection")
            MsgBox(BF.Deserialize("Data received: " & ReceiverClient.GetStream))
        End While
    End Sub
    Private Sub Listen()
        Try
            While ReceiverClient.Connected = False
                Receiver.Start()
                ReceiverClient = Receiver.AcceptTcpClient
            End While
            GetMessage.Start()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

You may find it easier to try this for yourself: all you need is 2 forms: Form1 and Form2, plus Form1 needs a button.

-Rixterz

Comment: When you are unable to get it to send, is it due to an exception or a network side problem? We'll need more details. If I were you, I'd put a breakpoint at each catch and get the exception details if there is one.

Comment: I found a different code that works; thanks for your interest anyway